# How can I add a codepen.io to ruby on rails? Using a example from codepen.io

Tags: ruby

http://codepen.io/iremlopsum/pen/OVMxzp

```
 Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code...
```

So I want to copy this project and build off it. My problem is I can't get it to change to pay, wrap, or ship. Any ideas? I'm using ruby on rails.

Comment: ...Why is 'thank you' in code?

Comment: Also, your title doesn't match your question. Your title asks how to do something, but your question indicates that you have and are now facing an issue. Please update either the question or the title so they're relevant to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the JavaScript in document ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// JS code from codepen.io here
});
```

The issue is the JavaScript tries to bind to the css classes before the HTML is rendered in the browser. So when it tries to bind go $(".pay") it will get an empty set and no events will be bound. So nothing happens. Another way you could fix it would be to move the JavaScript include tag to the bottom of the page (that way, the HTML will be rendered and present when the JS runs).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the pen, then select `embed` (it's in the left bottom). You can choose iframe, html, wordpress, then select the code and paste to your website.

[image]
The code will look like:

``See the Pen KwbrwK by duykhoa (@duykhoa) on CodePen.

``

*NOTES*: you may convert it to HAML or SLIM.